# How to parse a single TFRecord?

Tags: tensorflow

I have the code below:

```
def bytes_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image/encoded': bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
}))
```

I am now attempting to parse the TFRecord by doing:

```
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    tf_example, 
    features={'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string)}
)
```

But, I keep getting the error:
`Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.core.example.example_pb2.Example'> to Tensor.`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type of object are you converting to tfrecords? Are you parsing as part of Dataset API pipeline?

Comment: Parsing as part of the Object Detection API.

Comment: Then add more code. It's hard to tell what's wrong without knowing what you're trying to pass into `parse_single_example`

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a similar problem currently